# how to make my python code more effective

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was given a task in school to get a file basic math exercises (+,-,*,/) and i was told i need to solve these with python and write the answers in new file , i did finish my code and its working but i dont think my code is as efficient as the teacher expects .  i assume that there are spaces between first num , operation and second num but it is not Necessarily true.
Example for question. txt -
1234 + 12121
12 * 33
Example for answer. txt -
1234 + 12121 = 13,355
12 * 33 = 396

```
  ~with open(r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\que.txt", 'r') as source:
    index = 0
    t = source.readlines()
    while index < len(t):
        frs = ""
        sign = ""
        sec = ""
        for chr in t[index]:
            if chr == " ":
                break
            frs += chr 
        now = False 
        for chr in t[index]:
            if chr == " ":
                now = True
            elif now :
                sign = chr 
                break
        count = 0
        for chr in t[index]:
            if chr == " ":
                count += 1 
            elif count == 2:
                sec += chr
        frs = int(frs)
        sec = int(sec)
        with open(r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\answer.txt", 'a') as des:
            des.write(f"{frs} {sign} {sec} = {frs+sec}\n")
            index+=1
```

Comment: Show the que.txt file

Comment: can you give more context of what you want to archieve, i.e. inputs and outputs

Comment: And show what the expected output is for the given input.

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no need for security you could use exec to get a much shorter and easier solution.

```
with open(r"C:\Users\שליו\Desktop\que.txt", 'r') as source:
    with open(r"C:\Users\שליו\Desktop\answer.txt", 'a') as des:
        for equation in source.readlines():
            try:
                exec("result = " + equation)
                des.write(f"{equation.replace("\n","")} = {result}\n")
                print(f"calculated result {result}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"failed at {equation.replace("\n",""} because of {e}")
```

### EDIT:

Version that OP eventually used from comment:

```
def my_exec(code): 
    exec('global i; i = %s' % code) 
    global i 
    return i

def calc(): 
    with open(r"C:\Users\שליו\Desktop\que.txt", 'r') as source: 
        with open(r"C:\Users\שליו\Desktop\answer.txt", 'a') as des: 
            for equation in source.readlines(): 
                result = my_exec(equation) 
                a = equation.replace("\n","") 
                des.write(f"{a} = {result}\n")
```

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in line 6. Try again :-) It worked for me.

Comment: nothing , the code dont even writing , I believe an exception occurs but i am not sure which

Comment: found out that the code dont reconize the variable result

Comment: I tested it again with the examples your provided and I get `- 1234 + 12121 = 10887` and `12 * 33 = 396`. I added some debugging code for you, so that you see what could be wrong. Maybe comment the error if you get another one.

Comment: i got  - NameError: name 'rstrip' is not defined

Comment: Ah, Ok. Gess you are using an older version of python than me. Fixed it.

Comment: result is not defined

Comment: Hey, what Python-Version are you using?Also: Did you actually execute the code or is that just what your IDE says?

Comment: i did excute the code , the error is on the cmd window popping and im using python 3.7 on vs , and i use this version because it is the maximum version vs supports

Comment: Then I have no clue, what is wrong. As I said, it works perfectly on my machine. Sorry.

Comment: this is what i eventually used , fixed all my issues -

    def calc():
        with open(r"C:\Users\שליו\Desktop\que.txt", 'r') as source:
            with open(r"C:\Users\שליו\Desktop\answer.txt", 'a') as des:
                for equation in source.readlines():
                    result = my_exec(equation)
                    a = equation.replace("\n","")
                    des.write(f"{a} = {result}\n")
    def my_exec(code):
        exec('global i; i = %s' % code)
        global i
        return i

Comment: Ok. Nice workaround. Added it to the answer, so that it is properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would have approached

```
with open("input.txt", 'r') as source:
    for equation in source.readlines():
        frs = ""
        sign = ""
        sec = ""
        for index, char in enumerate(equation):
            if char == '+' or char == '-' or char =='*' or char =='/':
                sign = char
                frs = int(equation[:index])
                sec = int(equation[index + 1:])
                break
        # when we reach here, we would have found our operands and the operator
        ans = ""
        if char == '+':
            ans = frs + sec
        elif char == '-':
            ans = frs - sec
        elif char == '*':
            ans = frs * sec
        elif char == '/':
            ans = frs / sec
        else:
            print("Unsupported Character:", char)
            exit()
        with open("output.txt", 'a') as des:
            des.write(f"{frs} {sign} {sec} = {ans}\n")
```

Input.txt file is as follows:

```
1234 + 12121
12 * 33
```

Output.txt file looks like this:

```
1234 + 12121 = 13355
12 * 33 = 396
```

Comment: i am getting - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+ 3666666666666664\n'

Comment: Fixed and also added input cases and the output that I got